# Responsive font size using CSS/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I want to create a responsive text inside a div.

I tried [jquery-textfill](https://github.com/jquery-textfill/jquery-textfill) and [FlowType](http://simplefocus.com/flowtype/demo.html), but they are not working for me at all.

**FlowType** does not use all the available space, only a part of it ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FXL9k/145/)), while **textfill** does not respect the height ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FXL9k/146/)).

Am I using them incorrecly or what I want is too hard to achieve?

My HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="external">
        <div class="internal">Example</div>
    </div>    
</body>
```

My CSS:

```
.internal{width:100%;height:100%}
.external{width:400px;height:50px;}
```

PS. Viewports are not supported enough for now.

Comment: Can you describe what you mean by "responsive text"? How is it supposed to respond exactly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EDIT: Updated with `resize` event listener. Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/flowstoneknight/2xt9t8pg/).

As I understand it, you want the text to be as large as possible while still fitting inside the containing `<div>`, correct? My solution is to put a `<span>` around the text, which conforms to the text's normal size. Then calculate the ratios between the container's dimensions and the `<span>`'s dimensions. Whichever is the smaller ratio (either width or height), use that ratio to enlarge the text.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <span class="text-fitter">
        text here
    </span>
</div>
```

JS (jQuery):

```
textfit();
$(window).on('resize', textfit);

function textfit() {
    $('.text-fitter').css('font-size', 'medium');
    var w1 = $('.container').width()-10;
    var w2 = $('.text-fitter').width();
    var wRatio = Math.round(w1 / w2 * 10) / 10;

    var h1 = $('.container').height()-10;
    var h2 = $('.text-fitter').height();
    var hRatio = Math.round(h1 / h2 * 10) / 10;

    var constraint = Math.min(wRatio, hRatio);

    $('.text-fitter').css('font-size', constraint + 'em');
}
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/flowstoneknight/2xt9t8pg/). Adjust the `.container` dimensions in the CSS to see it in action.

Comment: Yes, that's what I wanted. Although, I think we should also add some JS listener in order to react to resizing browser window.

Comment: @dev9 Again, you'll need to be a little more specific. What changes when the window is resized? In your question, `.external` has a set width (400px), so it wouldn't change on resize, so the text size wouldn't change either. Please actually describe what you want. "React to resizing" is too vague.

Comment: I want what you've posted. The tricky thing is I do not control the `.external` div - so it should work if its size is set to specific value OR if its size is set to `auto` or `x %`

Comment: @dev9 Updated answer. In the future, please be clear about your specifications, as that affects what kinds of answers will help you.

Comment: Thank you, but your updated fiddle does not cover entire text, only a part of it.

Comment: @dev9 What does that mean? What doesn't cover the entire text? Please be clear...

Comment: The example text goes beyond the yellow div.

Comment: @dev9 I'm guessing the text gets split into two lines sometimes when expanding the window? That's probably due to the `resize` event firing rapidly during most window resizes, and the browser can't keep up with the calculations. Not much I can do about that right now.

Answer (score 1):

**CSS**

```
.internal{width:100%;height:100%}
.external{width:auto;height:auto;background-color:yellow}
```

**JQuery**

```
$(".external").fitText(0.5);
```

[**DEMO 1**](http://jsfiddle.net/hamix/FXL9k/147/)

> Update 1:

**CSS**

```
.internal{width:auto;height:auto;position:absolute;}
.external{width:400px;height:50px;background-color:yellow;position:relative;}
```

**JQuery**

```
$(".external").fitText();
```

[***DEMO 2***](http://jsfiddle.net/hamix/FXL9k/148/)

> Update 2:

**JQuery**

```
var ex=$(".external");
var h=ex.height();
var w=ex.width();
ex.fitText(Math.min(h,w)/Math.max(h,w) );
```

[**DEMO 3**](http://jsfiddle.net/hamix/FXL9k/151/)

> Update 4:

Bigtext is a jQuery text plugin that automatically enlarge the font size of your text to fill its parent container, without overflowing the container `Div`.
[**jQuery Bigtext Plugin**](http://www.jqueryscript.net/text/Dynamically-Resize-Text-Size-To-Fit-Container-Size-jQuery-Bigtext-Plugin.html)

Comment: I don't want to make it AUTO. It is going to be a widget for 3rd party users. Some of them will probably assign some constant value to HEIGHT or WIDTH.

Comment: See ``Update 1`` in my answer.

Comment: You must increase the height and width together.

Comment: in your fiddle  ``$(".external").fitText(0.5);``

Comment: But that's my whole point. I want to adjust the font even if width and height does not corelate. EDIT: no, adding 0.5 does not make it work

Comment: Your answer in ``Update 2``

Comment: The last solution for you in ``Update 4``

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who stumbles upon this old post, I have found a solution I consider perfect.

You take this beautiful plugin written by Dave Rupert, configure the settings to your liking, and I added a wrapper for it that allows you to define the elements you want to resize. It also stores the original font size so when you scale back up, the text is limited by it's original size, otherwise it scales without limit.

Here's a snippet and a jsfiddle. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/josh_bradley/7wux8a46/2/)

NOTE: the snippet only runs on resize in JSFiddle so be sure to resize your screen. In production it runs on load.

```js
var headings = [$('h1'), $('h2'), $('h3')]

  $.each(headings, function(index, heading) {

    var fontsize = heading.css('font-size');
    $(window).on('load resize', function() {
      if (heading.parent()[0] &&
        heading.parent()[0].scrollWidth > $('.container').innerWidth()) {
        heading.fitText(1, {
          minFontSize: '10px',
          maxFontSize: fontsize
        });
      }
    });
  });


  /*global jQuery */
  /*!
   * FitText.js 1.2
   *
   * Copyright 2011, Dave Rupert http://daverupert.com
   * Released under the WTFPL license
   * http://sam.zoy.org/wtfpl/
   *
   * Date: Thu May 05 14:23:00 2011 -0600
   */

  $.fn.fitText = function(kompressor, options) {
    // Setup options
    var compressor = kompressor || 1,
      settings = $.extend({
        'minFontSize': Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY,
        'maxFontSize': Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY
      }, options);
    return this.each(function() {
      // Store the object
      var $this = $(this);
      // Resizer() resizes items based on the object width divided by the compressor * 10
      var resizer = function() {
        $this.css('font-size', Math.max(Math.min($this.width() / (compressor * 10), parseFloat(settings.maxFontSize)), parseFloat(settings.minFontSize)));
      };
      // Call once to set.
      resizer();
      // Call on resize. Opera debounces their resize by default.
      $(window).on('resize.fittext orientationchange.fittext', resizer);
    });
  };
```

```css
.container {
  width: 80vw;
  background: yellow;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 5rem;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 4rem;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 3rem;
}

h4 {
  font-size: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <h1>GIGANTICFONT</h1>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <h2>LargishFont</h2>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <h3>Mediumfont</h3>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <h4>smallfont</h4>
</div>
```