# Change font size for mobile devices using JavaScript/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been looking through old posts and tried a few things but nothing seemed to work. I am trying to make the font size of h1, h2 and h3 all change in size when the device width is below 480px.

I am aware using css media query is a better way of doing this, however for the project I am working on this is not an option.

Thanks in advance:)

Here is my code in a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Eddie19/3ky01w6x/)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    if($(window).width() < 480) { 
         $('h1').css('font-size','10px');
         $('h2').css('font-size','8px');
         $('h3').css('font-size','6px');
    }
});
```

```css
h1 {
 font-size:50px;
    }
    h2 {
     font-size: 40px;
    }
    h3{
     font-size: 35px;
    }
```

```html
<h1>This is H1</h1>
<h2>This is H2</h2>
<h3>This is H3</h3>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Responsive font size using CSS/jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25742441/responsive-font-size-using-css-jquery)

Comment: Why is CSS not an option? CSS should always be an option

Comment: @HerrSerker its to be used in a master script file, I would use css but it cant be integrated in to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    if($(window).width() < 480) { 
         $('h1').css('font-size','10px');
         $('h2').css('font-size','8px');
         $('h3').css('font-size','6px');
         $('h4').css('font-size','4px');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>hi</h1>
<h2>hi</h2>
<h3>hi</h3>
<h4>hi</h4>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I have updated my JSFiddle to use this. However, I am getting and error 'Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined'. Have you got any ideas? It also isnt changing the font size.

Comment: please add jquery reference in your answer

Comment: I have edited my question show show what I have now included.

Comment: share your fiddle link

Comment: there are some mistakes in your fiddle

Comment: This still isnt working mate, thank you for your help though

Comment: $("h1").css({"font-size":"42px"}); instead of $("#h1").css({"font-size":"42px"});

Comment: Is the text decreasing in size when the window width is shrunk to below 600px?

Comment: do one thing instead of 42px add 10px and see weather it worked or not